# How to view themes in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i installed theme using magento connect.Then in configuration ->Design->Themes->default name is also entered in the field.Then cms ->pages ->Home page.The default  page is present.But theme is not displayed here.What i have to do.please any one suggest for this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache from "var/cache" folder?

Comment: Thanks for your  reply.i tried my own finally got the answer but now i need to customize the theme can you help me?

Comment: Yes please let me know what exact customization you are looking in the theme so that I can help you.

Comment: Hope this link helps http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned the Theme / Package Name in the configuration ->Design->Themes->default.

1st you have to mention the package name and then default. You have to mention this at two places in the configuration.

Comment: Please do not include signatures at all, or external links unless relevant to your answer. Some users may see this as spam, and flag your posts as such.

Comment: I need to give  the background image for the content. In the path( magneto->admin->cms->static block ).example   css:   .footer {
             background: url(/media/wysiwyg/IMG_01.jpg);
               }     example div:<div class=footer>image </div>I used this example but it not show me the background image .Can anyone suggest for this ?Advance Thanks

Comment: The height for the image should not be accepted In  the static blocks i applied what i have to do .can anyone suggest for this?